# Creating an R markdown/notebook template file: can I define code chunks to be folded when the `.rmd` file is opened in Rstudio?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, rnotebook

I'm creating a template file for R markdown / R notebook. There are several code chunks that I wish will remain folded when the `.rmd` is being opened. Is this possible?

### Example

Let's say that we have the following code, and we save it (without the `##`) into a file named `my_file.rmd`

````
## ---
## title: "R Notebook"
## output: html_notebook
## ---

## # step 0 -- my predefind functions
## ```{r my_func()}
## my_func <- function(x) {
##   x + 1
## }
## ```

## ```{r my_func_2()}
## my_func_2 <- function(x) {
##   x / 6
## }
## ```

## # step 1 -- your code here
## ```{r}

## ```
````

Is there a way we can open `my_file.rmd` — using RStudio — with the chunks `{r my_func()}` and `{r my_func_2()}` being *folded* upon opening the file?

Comment: I believe Rstudio has some IDE code folding feature, but it has to be when defining functions

Comment: @DanielJachetta, I'm not sure I understand your comment. What do you mean by "*when defining the functions*"?

Answer (score 0):

You coud use `code_folding: hide` YAML combined with `class.source = 'fold-show'` for he chuncks you want to show, [see](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/fold-show.html#fold-show):

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
---

# step 0 -- my predefined functions
```{r my_func()}
my_func <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}
```

```{r my_func_2()}
my_func_2 <- function(x) {
  x / 6
}
```

# step 2 -- your code here
```{r class.source = 'fold-show'}
my_func_3 <- function(x) {
  x / 6
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: thanks! But my question is aimed at the `.rmd` file (the source code), not the `html` output.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a proper R chunks, you can fold the code inside the Rmd in Rstudio. I highly suggest you read up on [knitr spin()](https://deanattali.com/2015/03/24/knitrs-best-hidden-gem-spin/) too
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not how to fold, but how to have the folded chunk remain folded when *re-*opening the `.rmd` file next time.

Comment: The next best thing is just a keyboard shortcut for folding the Chunk while in the IDE for hopefully a faster workflow. `Fold Selected  windows(Alt+L)  MacOS(Cmd+Option+L)`